# How to edit the XSL for RSS Viewer Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

I am using a blog site as a source for my RSS Feed. As I see the RSS feed, its showing up as the following ::
Blog: Posts
Test
Thursday, March 04, 2010 -

**Body**: 
With 25 four's and 3 sixers Sachin crosses 200 (147 balls) runs in an single ODI innings. Creates another world record.  Watch the final over where he got it double hundred with MSD    on the other end.

This is what he had to say after getting the MOM (man of the match): I dedicate this knock to all the people of India, who have supported me throughout over the last 20 years. I was timing the ball well, and I felt that anywhere between 340 to 350 was a good target. I thought Karthik, Yusuf and Dhoni supported me well. I thought that a 200 would be possible once I crossed 175 in the 42nd over. I am enjoying my cricket at the moment. There have been a few bad decisions I have made as a batsman, but as long as the passion is there I will carry on. It feels good that I lasted the 50 overs, it was a good test of my fitness and I would like to do this once again.

Well!!! Wait for more.

**Published**: 3/4/2010 3:18 PM

More...

I actually wanted to remove the **Body**, **Published** parameters. I just want my XSLT to be able to show only the Description of the blog. No need to have this meta data.

Can anyone help me in specifying tthe XSL changes?

Comment: Please format your sample code (indent 4 spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a severe search over the RSS feed webpart on my SharePoint site, I got the answer to my question. Please follow the following steps to achieve the above functionality::
1. Logon to your SharePoint site
2. Navigate to the blog site which is the source for the RSS feed webpart.
3. Go to List settings
4. Click on RSS Settings
5. Deselect all columns except Body
6. Save the settings

Now check the RSS Feed webpart. All the metadata tags are removed.

The text given in the question looks as below::

With 25 four's and 3 sixers Sachin crosses 200 (147 balls) runs in an single ODI innings. Creates another world record. Watch the final over where he got it double hundred with MSD on the other end.

This is what he had to say after getting the MOM (man of the match): I dedicate this knock to all the people of India, who have supported me throughout over the last 20 years. I was timing the ball well, and I felt that anywhere between 340 to 350 was a good target. I thought Karthik, Yusuf and Dhoni supported me well. I thought that a 200 would be possible once I crossed 175 in the 42nd over. I am enjoying my cricket at the moment. There have been a few bad decisions I have made as a batsman, but as long as the passion is there I will carry on. It feels good that I lasted the 50 overs, it was a good test of my fitness and I would like to do this once again.

Well!!! Wait for more.

Answer (score 0):

This worked although just checking Body and deselecting everything else was not very intuitive. Here are the selections for Sharepoint 2010:

1. Logon to your Sharepoint site
2. Navigate to the blog site which is the source for the RSS feed webpart
3. Select Site Settings
4. In the Site Administrator Section select "Site Libraries and Lists"
5. Select the option to "customize: posts"
6. Click on the RSS Settings
7. Deselect (uncheck) all the columns and just select (check) Body
8. Save the settings.

You may need to restart the Outlook client accessing the RSS Feed to see the view change; it may also be necessary to delete the old RSS entry in Outlook and recreate it in order for the "Body:" to disappear.